# Why does WebView in the SDK source code extend MockView?

Tags: android, webview

In my android studio, I find the WebView source code, but it seems to be empty, and the top comment is:

```
/**
* Mock version of the WebView.
* Only non override public methods from the real WebView have been added in there.
* Methods that take an unknown class as parameter or as return object, have been removed for now.
* 
* TODO: generate automatically.
*
*/
```

But in the [github android source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/webkit/WebView.java), it is not like this, and it seems this is the real `WebView`.

So my question is why there are the the two different `WebView` source codes, and what is `MockView`？

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the provided scope, the `WebView` in `android.jar` is a mock version, which is only for development purpose, with the mock version webview you can render the webview in the layout window, you can call the API in your code.

In the runtime scope, the `WebView` will be replaced.

Comment: even for android Test ? Because I figured out that even with android Tests, it uses the WebView extended to MockView.java. class or at least I think it uses...

Comment: I'm trying to access `onResume` and `onPause` of webview but can't do it. Is there something I change to get access?